# cassandra on ubuntu installation error

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I'm trying to install Cassandra 3.7 .
when i check  bin/nodetool -f it shows

```
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  129.3 KiB  256          100.0%            40170e85-795e-43b1-bd57-68da9267ecc5  rack1
```

but when i try to run bin/cqlsh this shows the error

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments',)})
```

please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure which operating system you are using, however we faced similar kind of issue with Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS. Things were working fine when we were using Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS. Then I got pointer on IRC channel of Cassandra. This was actually reported as bug [CASSANDRA-11850](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11850). If you follow through the work-around mentioned in comments, you can resolve this issue.

For quick reference, I am summarizing steps.
1) Update python Cassandra drivers from [Cassandra Drivers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cassandra-driver)
2) Before connecting to Cassandra using 'cqlsh' export CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=true. Then run 'cqlsh'.

This should solve your problem.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I was trying on ubuntu server 16, thank you now it's working  on ubuntu server 14